# How to name the Vserver (Linux) Hostname?

Tags: linux-vserver

Sorry in advance about my english, but I will try my best.

I have rent a Linux Vserver using Parallels Plesk Panel 11.
My Vserver-Provider generated a hostname for the server. But now I would like to change the hostname of the Server. I know how to change the hostname. That's not the problem.

First Question/Problem is:
I have bought a Domain, in example: webhosting24.com. But do I have to rename my hostname to "webhosting24.com" or anything like "server.webhosting24.com"? Does it make any difference?

Because I would like to use the domain also for my own websites.

Second Question/Problem:
Do I have to enter "www" also by the hostname? In example: www.webhosting24.com?

Third Question/Problem:
If I set the nameserver for my other domains like:
ns.webhosting24.com and ns2.webhosting24.com, do I have to create a Subdomain called "ns.webhosting24.com" or will it be generated itself?

Sorry again for my english...

But thanks  a lot in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not. The hostname is just there to identify your server on the network. When you configure your web server (like Apache) you can give each virtual host its own domain name and they in no way have to be related to the server hostname.

I'm not sure I understand the third question. Are you hosting your own name servers? It'd probably be in your best interest to do hosted DNS. Sign up for a DNS service and then log in to your registrar where you bought the domain name and give them the domain names of your new DNS name servers. Depending on the registrar, they may even offer DNS services themselves.

Comment: Thank's for you're reply!

Does this mean that I could name my server's hostname "webhosting24.com" without using "www" and creating a subdomain like "server.webhosting24.com"? Only "webhosting24.com", right?

But will I be also able to use the domain "webhosting24.com" for my own websites? Like: webhosting24.com/mywebsite/index.php?

Comment: Sure. If you want, you could set the server hostname to "mytotallyawesomeserverdude" and that would be fine (CAVEAT: I don't use Plesk, so I don't know if that will affect plesk in any way). Then when you configure Apache for your websites, you can assign whatever domain name you want for all your virtual hosts and it'll work as long as the DNS for those domain names point to your server.

Comment: Thank's again for you're reply. :)

Okay, I think I got it. 

The point for the third Question is: I have rent a V-Server by "https://www.hosteurope.de/en". 

I got for my other domains (in example: customer1.com, customer2.com, customer3.com and so on) a secondary nameserver from my provider hosteurope called: ns2.hans.hosteurope.de. I have registred the Domains on hosteurope. 

But I have to set the primary nameserver myself. So I thout I would name my own nameserver: "ns.webhosting24.com". But It's not working...

Of course, I have also set the A-Records "IP-Adresses".

Comment: Because you aren't running your own name server. If you registered the domains through hosteurope AND they provide your DNS, then it's just something you need to configure in your user account with them. I'm willing to bet they provide technical support as part of your service. You should probably give them a call to help you get that part working.

Comment: Thanks again! :)

Yeah, they do. But they want to configure every each domains DNS-Settings: 100€. Even if I would pay this, I would not know how they have done it. :( But thanks! I will try it again, maybe I have missed something to set...